# Is there a way to @Autowire a bean that requires constructor arguments?

Tags: spring, constructor, autowired, spring-annotations, spring-bean

I'm using Spring 3.0.5 and am using @Autowire annotation for my class members as much as possible.  One of the beans that I need to autowire requires arguments to its constructor.  I've looked through the Spring docs, but cannot seem to find any reference to how to annotate constructor arguments.

In XML, I can use  as part of the bean definition.  Is there a similar mechanism for @Autowire annotation?

Ex:

```
@Component
public class MyConstructorClass{

  String var;
  public MyConstructorClass( String constrArg ){
    this.var = var;
  }
...
}


@Service
public class MyBeanService{
  @Autowired
  MyConstructorClass myConstructorClass;

  ....
}
```

In this example, how do I specify the value of "constrArg" in MyBeanService with the @Autowire annotation?  Is there any way to do this?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, or perhaps I am misunderstanding, but I am not looking to autowire constrArg; I'm looking to autowire MyConstructorClass, but the constructor requires a String.  If I was using XML configuration, my bean defn would be:

Comment: If I was using XML configuration, my bean defn would be something like: 

<bean id="myBeanService" class="MyBeanService">
  <property name="myConstructorClass">
    <bean class="MyConstructorClass">
      <constructor-arg value="MyStringHere" />
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>

Is there a way to translate that into annotations?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You need the [`@Value`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation.

> A common use case is to assign default field values using
> `"#{systemProperties.myProp}"` style expressions.

```
public class SimpleMovieLister {

  private MovieFinder movieFinder;
  private String defaultLocale;

  @Autowired
  public void configure(MovieFinder movieFinder, 
                        @Value("#{ systemProperties['user.region'] }") String defaultLocale) {
      this.movieFinder = movieFinder;
      this.defaultLocale = defaultLocale;
  }

  // ...
}
```

**See:** [Expression Language > Annotation Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-annotation-based)

---

To be more clear: in your scenario, you'd wire two classes, `MybeanService` and `MyConstructorClass`, something like this:

```
@Component
public class MyBeanService implements BeanService{
    @Autowired
    public MybeanService(MyConstructorClass foo){
        // do something with foo
    }
}

@Component
public class MyConstructorClass{
    public MyConstructorClass(@Value("#{some expression here}") String value){
         // do something with value
    }
}
```

Update: if you need several different instances of `MyConstructorClass` with different values, you should [use Qualifier annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I don't understand how that relates to setting the constructor arg for the injected bean.  From what I can tell from the spring docs, it is good for setting default values, but doesn't specify how to pass a constructor arg.

Comment: @EricB. `@Value` is like `@Autowired` for string arguments.

Comment: @Eric B ([awesome username, btw :-)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_B._%26_Rakim)), I've added some sample code for illustration

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  The catch here is the requirement for me to have access to modify the MyConstructorClass code.  Unfortunately, that is not always the case; I don't necessarily have the ability to modify the code.  Additionally, in my example, I'm using a String as the argument, but there are cases where the contructor requires other beans as arguments.

Comment: @Eric well then you either need XML or [Java based configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)

Comment: Does this answer change if the constructor arg is a custom java object, ie not a String?

Comment: @KevinMeredith well it needs to be an Object Spring can convert, but then it works. However, if your value is a spring bean, you should use `@Autowired`, `@Inject`et al

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd In the question, an instance of `MyConstructorClass` is autowired to variable `myConstructorClass` in `MyBeanService`. In your example, there is no `myConstructorClass` variable there. I'm confused. Is it `foo` argument to be used instead of it?

Comment: @MikhailBatcer its says "do something with foo". for example: assign foo to a field :-)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd For example, to the field `private MyConstructorClass myConstructorClass;`, right? :-)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd  - i want to pass the value - "Value1" to the constructor , how can i do it , i tried your syntax , but it is not getting compiled , is it correct ..? can you pls help me

Comment: @AshishShetkar I think the answer contains a typo. Instead of `@Value("#{ systemProperties['user.region'] }"} String defaultLocale` it needs to be `@Value("#{ systemProperties['user.region'] }") String defaultLocale`. In my Spring-Boot 4 Project I needed to use `@Value("${user.region}") String defaultLocale` instead. Don't know the difference though.

Answer (score 25):

Well, from time to time I run into the same question. As far as I know, one cannot do that when one wants to add dynamic parameters to the constructor. However, the factory pattern may help.

```
public interface MyBean {
    // here be my fancy stuff
}

public interface MyBeanFactory {
    public MyBean getMyBean(/* bean parameters */);
}

@Component
public class MyBeanFactoryImpl implements MyBeanFactory {
    @Autowired
    WhateverIWantToInject somethingInjected;

    public MyBean getMyBean(/* params */) {
        return new MyBeanImpl(/* params */);
    }

    private class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean {
        public MyBeanImpl(/* params */) {
            // let's do whatever one has to
        }
    }
}

@Component
public class MyConsumerClass {
    @Autowired
    private MyBeanFactory beanFactory;

    public void myMethod() {
        // here one has to prepare the parameters
        MyBean bean = beanFactory.getMyBean(/* params */);
    }
}
```

Now, `MyBean` is not a spring bean per se, but it is close enough. Dependency Injection works, although I inject the factory and not the bean itself - one has to inject a new factory on top of his own new `MyBean` implementation if one wants to replace it.

Further, `MyBean` has access to other beans - because it may have access to the factory's autowired stuff.

And one might apparently want to add some logic to the `getMyBean` function, which is extra effort I allow, but unfortunately I have no better solution. Since the problem usually is that the dynamic parameters come from an external source, like a database, or user interaction, therefore I must instantiate that bean only in mid-run, only when that info is readily available, so the `Factory` should be quite adequate.

Answer (score 10):

> In this example, how do I specify the value of "constrArg" in `MyBeanService` with the `@Autowire` annotation? Is there any way to do this?

No, not in the way that you mean. The bean representing `MyConstructorClass` must be configurable without requiring any of its client beans, so `MyBeanService` doesn't get a say in how `MyConstructorClass` is configured.

This isn't an autowiring problem, the problem here is how does Spring instantiate `MyConstructorClass`, given that `MyConstructorClass` is a `@Component` (and you're using component-scanning, and therefore not specifying a `MyConstructorClass` explicitly in your config).

As @Sean said, one answer here is to use `@Value` on the constructor parameter, so that Spring will fetch the constructor value from a system property or properties file. The alternative is for `MyBeanService` to directly instantiate `MyConstructorClass`, but if you do that, then `MyConstructorClass` is no longer a Spring bean.

Comment: Can @Value be set to a fully qualified bean? And them via Autowiring it'll be found?

Answer (score 10):

You can also configure your component like this :

```
package mypackage;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
   @Configuration
   public class MyConstructorClassConfig {


   @Bean
   public MyConstructorClass myConstructorClass(){
      return new myConstructorClass("foobar");
   }
  }
}
```

With the `Bean` annotation, you are telling Spring to register the returned bean in the `BeanFactory`.

So you can autowire it as you wish.

Comment: Could you please tell how I can autowire e.g. a client I created in the MyConstructorClassConfig as shown above e.g. I have a createClient method annotated with a Bean, how do I use this createClient method in a service class?

Comment: What if the parameter is dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be instead of passing the parameters to the constructor you might have them as getter and setters and then in a @PostConstruct initialize the values as you want. In this case Spring will create the bean using the default constructor. An example is below

```
@Component
public class MyConstructorClass{

  String var;

  public void setVar(String var){
     this.var = var;
  }

  public void getVar(){
    return var;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
     setVar("var");
  }
...
}


@Service
public class MyBeanService{
  //field autowiring
  @Autowired
  MyConstructorClass myConstructorClass;

  ....
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even add much value. Instead of going through all this, just get your bean though BeanFactory in Configuration file and set your variables there.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers are fairly old, so it might have not been possible back then, but there actually is a solution that satisfies all the possible use-cases.

So right know the answers are:

- Not providing a real Spring component (the factory design)
- or does not fit every situation (using `@Value` you have to have the value in a configuration file somewhere)

The solution to solve those issues is to create the object manually using the `ApplicationContext`:

```
@Component
public class MyConstructorClass
{
    String var;

    public MyConstructorClass() {}
    public MyConstructorClass(String constrArg) {
        this.var = var;
    }
}

@Service
public class MyBeanService implements ApplicationContextAware
{
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    MyConstructorClass myConstructorClass;

    public MyBeanService()
    {
        // Creating the object manually
        MyConstructorClass myObject = new MyConstructorClass("hello world");
        // Initializing the object as a Spring component
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        factory.autowireBean(myObject);
        factory.initializeBean(myObject, myObject.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        applicationContext = context;
    }
}
```

This is a cool solution because:

- It gives you access to all the Spring functionalities on your object (`@Autowired` obviously, but also `@Async` for example),
- You can use any source for your constructor arguments (configuration file, computed value, hard-coded value, ...),
- It only requires you to add a few lines of code without having to change anything.
- It can also be used to dynamically create a unknown number of instances of a Spring-managed class (I'm using it to create multiple asynchronous executors on the fly for example)

The only thing to keep in mind is that you have to have a constructor that takes no arguments (and that can be empty) in the class you want to instantiate (or an `@Autowired` constructor if you need it).

Comment: whats the point of `MyConstructorClass myConstructorClass;`?  You never use it?  Did you to use `myConstructorClass` instead of `myObject`?

Comment: @Dan I honestly don't remember as it was a while back but yeah it might just be a mistake that I left or a variable that I was using before but ended up not needing.

Comment: Just came across this thread and it's quite old, but people still look at it, so shall comment: this approach can't work correctly, since the `applicationContext` object is used in the c~tor, while it is being set only after the object is constructed (don't let `static` to mislead you). So this c~tor should fail on NPE in it's second line, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, if you already have an instance of the object created and you want to add it as an @autowired dependency to initialize all the internal @autowired variables, could be the following:

```
@Autowired 
private AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory;

public void doStuff() {
   YourObject obj = new YourObject("Value X", "etc");
   autowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Zakaria's answer, but if you're in a project where your team doesn't want to use that approach, and you're stuck trying to construct something with a String, integer, float, or primative type from a property file into the constructor, then you can use Spring's `@Value` annotation on the parameter in the constructor.

For example, I had an issue where I was trying to pull a string property into my constructor for a class annotated with `@Service`. My approach works for `@Service`, but I  think this approach should work with any spring java class, if it has an annotation (such as `@Service`, `@Component`, etc.) which indicate that Spring will be the one constructing instances of the class.

Let's say in some yaml file (or whatever configuration you're using), you have something like this:

```yaml
some:
    custom:
        envProperty: "property-for-dev-environment"
```

and you've got a constructor:

```java
@Service // I think this should work for @Component, or any annotation saying Spring is the one calling the constructor.
class MyClass {
...
    MyClass(String property){
    ...
    }
...
}
```

This won't run as Spring won't be able to find the string `envProperty`. So, this is one way you can get that value:

```java
class MyDynamoTable
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
...
    MyDynamoTable(@Value("${some.custom.envProperty}) String property){
    ...
    }
...
```

In the above constructor, Spring will call the class and know to use the String `"property-for-dev-environment"` pulled from my yaml configuration when calling it.

NOTE: this I believe @Value annotation is for strings, intergers, and I believe primative types. If you're trying to pass custom classes (beans), then approaches in answers defined above work.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use @Autowired and @Value. Refer this [post](http://blog.fahimfarook.me/2014/11/spring-component-scan-with-non-default.html) for more information on this topic.

Comment: The answer is there thought it's short. The answer in essence is to you '@Autowired' and '@Value'. I could have added it as a comment but it's a long time back and I'm not sure I had comment privileges...