# Spring - autowire a class that have a constructor

Tags: java, spring, autowired

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anyway to @Autowire a bean that requires constructor arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739566/anyway-to-autowire-a-bean-that-requires-constructor-arguments)

In my controller I want to use @Autowired to inject a class using the method / constructor autowiring. for example using:

```
@Autowired 
private InjectedClass injectedClass;
```

My problem is that the injected class injectedClass have a constructor, and I need to pass a variable to the constructor from the controller. How can I pass values to the constructors?

Comment: Tim, I dont think this is a duplicat question

Answer (score 5):

If you are using annotations you can apply @Autowired annotation to MyClass's constructor, which will auto wire beans you are passing to MyClass's special constructor. Consider following e.g.

```
public class MovieRecommender {

  @Autowired
  private MovieCatalog movieCatalog;

  private CustomerPreferenceDao customerPreferenceDao;

  @Autowired
  public MovieRecommender(CustomerPreferenceDao customerPreferenceDao) {
      this.customerPreferenceDao = customerPreferenceDao;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: you miss understood me, I need a dynamic constructor for  CustomerPreferenceDao

Comment: @webmobileDev - You didn't mention that anywhere in your question...

Answer (score 3):

You can either mark private data members with `@Resource(name = "x")` annotation OR wire them using constructor injection in the application context XML.

Annotations and XML configuration can be mixed in Spring.  It need not be all or nothing.

```
<bean id="myClass" class="foo.bar.MyClass">
    <constructor-arg ref="yourArgRefHere"/> 
</bean>
```

Comment: but yourArgRefHere are some thing dynamic that i need to send by code

Comment: It's hard to tell without more context.  Maybe it shouldn't be under Spring's control; maybe you need a factory managed by Spring where you simply pass in the key.  I don't know.