# How to autowire a class with non-empty constructor?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I'd like to `@Autowired` a class that has a non-empty constructor.
Just the the following as an example, it does not necessairly have to be a view/service. Could be whatever component you like, having non-default constructor:

```
@Component
class MyViewService {
  //the "datasource" to show in the view
  private List<String> companies companies;
  private MyObject obj;

  public MyViewService(List<String> companies, MyObject obj) {
    this.companies = companies;
    this.obj = obj;
  }
}
```

Of course I cannot just write

```
@Autowired
private MyViewService viewService;
```

as I'd like to use the constructor with the list. But how?

Are there better approaches than refactoring these sort of constructors to `setters`? I wouldn't like this approach as ideally the constructor forces other classes to provide all objects that are needed within the service. If I use setters, one could easily forget to set certain objects.

Comment: Well you can add @Autowire to the constructor. Works similar to setter injecton.

Comment: `public(List<String> companies, MyObject obj)` is nonsense.  do you actually mean `public MyViewService(List<String> companies, MyObject obj)`?

Comment: How would Spring known what to pass as constructor parameters?

Comment: @Dwb yes of course, corrected above.

Comment: @sp00m no I'd like to pass the objects myself. These are not objects that can be autowired.

Comment: @Icewind yes I know, but this would require the `List<String> companies` to be a spring managed bean, which is not intended.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739566/anyway-to-autowire-a-bean-that-requires-constructor-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Spring to manage `MyViewService` you have to tell Spring how to create an instance of it.  If you're using XML configuration:

```
<bean id="myViewService" class="org.membersound.MyViewService">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="ref_to_list" />
  <constructor-arg index="1" ref="ref_to_object" />
</bean>
```

If you're using Java configuration then you'd call the constructor yourself in your `@Bean`annotated method.

Check out the [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection) on this topic.  To address a comment you made to another answer, you can [create a List bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-list) in XML as shown in the Spring docs.  If the list data isn't fixed (which it's probably not) then you want to use an [instance factory method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method) to instantiate the bean.

In short, the answers you seek are all in the Spring docs :)

Comment: OK I see. But one question remains taking eg my example: is it good practice to make data-supplying lists a spring-managed bean? I mean, this list would be probably only used for this particular service, and only in this constructor.

Comment: It's not a bad practice - it just depends on the problem you're trying to solve.  If the elements of the list are known in advance then it's better to put them into a properties file and have Spring inject the values from the file.

Comment: You can actually use list tags to specify the list in-place! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416056/how-to-define-a-list-bean-in-spring

Answer (score 0):

If a component has a non-default constructor then you need to configure the constructor in the bean configuration.

If you are using XML,
it might look like this (example from the [spring reference document](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/)):

```
<beans>
    <bean id="foo" class="x.y.Foo">
        <constructor-arg ref="bar"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="baz"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="bar" class="x.y.Bar"/>
    <bean id="baz" class="x.y.Baz"/>
</beans>
```

The key here is constructor wiring of the bean that will be used for the @AutoWire.
The way you use the bean has no impact.

Comment: Taking my example, how would I make a `List<String> companies` a spring managed bean? Does it make sense at all to have a list of objects managed?

Comment: If you are using XML, configure a util:list bean that contains the list of companies.  the Paul answer demonstrates this.