# How to Autowire a 1-arg Object Constructor with Previously Autowired Object?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Given the following `MyConstructorClass`:

```
@Component
public class MyConstructorClass{

  MyObj var;
  public MyConstructorClass( MyObj constrArg ){
    this.var = var;
  }
...
}
```

How can I autowire a field that requires a constructor argument from a previously `@Autowired` field? Below is an example.

Note - this question, I believe, is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6739566/409976), except that my constructor argument is **not** a String. This code sample is slightly modified from this question.

```
@Service
public class MyBeanService{

  @Autowired               
  CustomObject customObj;                // no arguments to constructor

  @Autowired
  MyConstructorClass myConstructorClass; // requires `customObj` as an argument

  ....
}
```

How can I modify `MyBeanService` to properly construct `myConstructorClass` with `customObj`?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to annotated the constructor of MyConstructorClass with `@Autowired`:

```
@Component
public class MyConstructorClass {
    final private CustomObject customObj;

    @Autowired 
    public MyConstructorClass(CustomObject customObj) {
        this.customObj = customObj;
    }
}
```

Another alternative, (without adding the `@Autowired` constructor to MyConstructorClass) is to  use a `@Configuration` bean:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {         

     @Bean 
     public CustomObject customObj() {
        return customObj;
     }

     @Bean 
     public MyConstructorClass myConstructorClass() {
        return new MyConstructorClass(customObj());
     }

     @Bean
     public MyBeanService myBeanService() {
         return new MyBeanService();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `<constructor-arg>` in your servlet

```
<bean id="myConstructorClass" class="package.MyConstructorClass">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="package.CustomObject"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only place you need to use that class could use @PostConstruct to instantiate itself. I think there is a better solution, but this is off the top of my head.

```
@Service
public class MyBeanService{

  @Autowired               
  CustomObject customObj;

  MyConstructorClass myConstructorClass;      

  @PostConstruct
  public void construct()
  {
    myConstructorClass = new MyConstructorClass(customObj);
  }
}
```

Comment: so, `MyConstructorClass`, in this case, wouldn't need to be a Spring-managed bean, is that right?

Comment: Yeah, if you aren't at all interested sharing the MyConstructorClass instance and the dependencies are simple you could do it this way, but  the answer Ricardo Veguilla provided is better and more flexible down the road.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, you can refer to other beans defined in Spring.

```
<bean id="myConstructorClass" class="package.MyConstructorClass">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="customObj"/>
</bean>
```