# Spring annotations confusion

Tags: java, spring

i am really confused with spring annotations. 
where to use @ Autowired, where class is @ Bean or @ Component,

i understand we cannot use

```
 Example example=new Example("String");
```

in Spring
but how alone

```
@Autowired
Example example;
```

will solve the purpose?
what about Example Constructor ,how spring will provide String value to Example Constructor?

i went through one of the article but it does not make much sense to me.
it would be great if some one can give me just brief and simple explanation.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739566/anyway-to-autowire-a-bean-that-requires-constructor-arguments

Comment: All these questions are answered in [the official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring doesn't say you can't do `Example example = new Example("String");`  That is still perfectly legal if `Example` does not need to be a singleton bean.  Where `@Autowired` and `@Bean` come into play is when you want to instantiate a class as a singleton.  In Spring, any bean you annotate with `@Service`, `@Component` or `@Repository` would get automatically registered as a singleton bean as long as your component scanning is setup correctly.  The option of using `@Bean` allows you to define these singletons without annotating the classes explicitly.  Instead you would create a class, annotate it with `@Configuration` and within that class, define one or more `@Bean` definitions.

So instead of

```
@Component
public class MyService {
    public MyService() {}
}
```

You could have

```
public class MyService {
    public MyService() {}
}

@Configuration
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public MyService myService() {
        return new MyService();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public MyOtherService myOtherService(MyService myService) {
        return new MyOtherService();
    }
}
```

The trade-off is having your beans defined in one place vs annotating individual classes.  I typically use both depending on what I need.

Comment: this is not the idea of spring. You should never use `new {ConcreteImplementation}` in your code.

Comment: Autowired on a method works similar to constructor, but I prefer constructor since your singleton bean will only be instantiated if the required dependencies are met.  Method injection is less reliable I believe.

Comment: @dit this was just an example.

Answer (score 2):

You will first define a bean of type example:

```
<beans>
    <bean name="example" class="Example">
        <constructor-arg value="String">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

or in Java code as:

```
@Bean
public Example example() {
    return new Example("String");
}
```

Now when you use `@Autowired` the spring container will inject the bean created above into the parent bean.

Comment: i can use this **@Bean** in same class where i am using @Autowire ?

Comment: @Tajinder yes I think that should be ok - you can easily try it out and check if it works

Answer (score 1):

Default constructor + `@Component` - Annotation is enough to get `@Autowired` work:

```
@Component
public class Example {

    public Example(){
        this.str = "string";
    }

}
```

You should never instantiate a concrete implementation via `@Bean` declaration. Always do something like this:

```
public interface MyApiInterface{

    void doSomeOperation();

}

@Component
public class MyApiV1 implements MyApiInterface {

    public void doSomeOperation() {...}

}
```

And now you can use it in your code:

```
@Autowired
private MyApiInterface _api; // spring will AUTOmaticaly find the implementation
```

Comment: and what does @ Autowired on some method represents ?

Comment: @Tajinder the same. `@Autowired` means "find automaticaly implementation and create it via new"