# spring how to instantiate an @Autowired constructor without passing the parameter

Tags: java, spring

Let's say I have this class

```
class Foo implements IFoo { Foo() {} }
class Fooz implements IFoo { Fooz() {}}

class Foobar implement IFoobar {
  @Autowired
  Foobar (Foo foo) {}
}

class Foobarz implement IFoobar {
  @Autowired
  Foobarz (Bar bar) {}
}
```

In asimple case I can do to solve my problem:

```
class Bar {
  @Autowired 
  Bar (IFoo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}
```

However if I want to be able to select my IFoo and IFoobar instance according to my configuration file I need to do do:

```
@Configuration
class Configuration {
  @Bean
  foo () {
    return this.isZ() ? new Fooz() : new Foo ();
  }
  @Bean
  foobar () {
    return this.isZ() ? new Foobarz(/* ??????? */) : new Foobar (/* ??????? */);
  }
}
```

As you can see I can't instantiate my Foobar, since I need another bean. I know there is the ApplicationContext.getBean, but I can't be sure it will be indeed initialized in my `Configuration` class when  `foobar()` gets called.

And I don't want to call `this.foo()` either, because that would create another reference of the object, and I'm not sure about the order of execution and initialization

Comment: what version of Spring are you currently using? 4+?

Comment: I'm using 5.0.9

Comment: You can pass parameters to `@Bean` methods, and you can call other `@Bean` methods from `@Bean` methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anyway to @Autowire a bean that requires constructor arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739566/anyway-to-autowire-a-bean-that-requires-constructor-arguments)

Comment: See also `@Conditional` or `@Profile` to decide which implementation to use.

Comment: @Conditional works well with spring, although IntelliJ is ignoring it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case following should do the trick

```
@Configuration
class Configuration {
  @Bean
  IFoo foo() {
    return this.isZ() ? new Fooz() : new Foo ();
  }
  @Bean
  IFoobar foobar(IFoo foo) { // IFoo bean declared above will be injected here by Spring
    return this.isZ() ? new Foobarz(foo) : new Foobar(foo);
  }
}
```

**UPDATED**

But more elegant way to do it is just to put `@Service` or `@Component` annotation on your class (`@Bean` declaration should be **removed** from configuration though) ...

```
package com.foobarpkg.maybeanotherpkg;

@Service 
class Foobar implement IFoobar {
  @Autowired
  Foobar (IFoo foo) { // not that interface should be used here instead of concrete class (Foo/Fooz)
  } 
}
```

... and let Spring know its package is located at

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.foobarpkg"})
class Configuration { 
 @Bean
  IFoo foo() {
    return this.isZ() ? new Fooz() : new Foo ();
  }
  // foobar bean is no longer declared here
}
```

Comment: This looks to be what I was looking for even though it's not the optimal answer, thanks anyway!