# Should I instantiate my Service in order to share infornation between different methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Currently I have an endpoint in my controller that calls different methods from my service. Each of these methods recieve a parameter called `executionId` that is different for every http request.

```java
@RestController
public class ProcedureController {

    @Autowired
    MyService service;

    @GetMapping
    public void execute(){
        String executionId = ...; //randomly generated

        service.executeMethodA(executionId);
        service.executeMethodB(executionId);
    }

}
```

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

    public void executeMethodA(String executionId){
        ...
    }

    public void executeMethodB(String executionId){
        ...
    }

}
```

It works fine but it seems very repetitive to pass `executionId` as a parameter to each method. So one solution that I thought was to instantiate my service with the executionId so it can hold this information and every method can access it.

```js
@RestController
public class ProcedureController {

    @GetMapping
    public void execute(){
        String executionId = ...; //randomly generated

        MyService service = new MyService(executionId);

        service.executeMethodA();
        service.executeMethodB();
    }

}
```

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

    String executionId;

    public MyService(String executionId){
        this.executionId = executionId;
    }

    public void executeMethodA(){
        // Use executionId here
        ...
    }

    public void executeMethodB(){
        // Use executionId here
        ...
    }

}
```

Is this solution a bad practice? If so, how can I achieve something similar?

Comment: I hope this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739566/is-there-a-way-to-autowire-a-bean-that-requires-constructor-arguments)  will help you to understand

Comment: @VivekJain With this solution it doesn't look like it's possible to construct my service with a dynamic parameter for each http request made to the api.

Comment: try to set scope of your bean as request, I hope this should work for you.

Comment: visit this [page](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/request-scope.html)

Comment: @VivekJain it worked perfectly. If you want to, please edit you answer to refer to this last page you sent.

Answer (score 0):

Spring allows you to inject a managed object (bean) as a dependency into another object via the @Autowired annotation.

For example, if I have a UserService that has a dependency on UserRepository, I can have the UserRepository injected using @Autowired annotation like this:

*UserRepository Class*

```java
class UserRepository {
UserRepository () {}
}
```

*UserService Class*

```java
class UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

UserService () {}

}
```

This is done using Field Injection. The same thing can be accomplice using Setter Injection:

```java
class UserService {

private UserRepository userRepository;

UserService () {}

@Autowired // Using setter injection
public void setUserRepository(
UserRepository userRepository) {
this.userRepository = userRepository
}

}
```

or via Constructor Injection:

```
class UserService {

private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired // Using constructor Injection
UserService (UserRepository userRepository) {
this.userRepository = userRepository
}

}
```

Comment: "executionId" is randomly generated for each request, I didn't get how can I set this field in my service with the post that you shared. Could you show me an example?

Comment: follow the above example and just set the scope of your bean as request.